# Fail to read information from a web site using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried to use "UrlFetchApp.Fetch" in google apps script to retrieve data from https://metoc.ndbc.noaa.gov/web/guest/jtwc".

However, the information highlighted in  red as shown here ["web capture"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB7vC.png) cannot be captured in the file I downloaded. Please help, thanks.

```
var FILE_NAME = 'data.txt'
var Google_DRive_ID = 'your google drive folder id'
var RESOURCE_URL = 'https://metoc.ndbc.noaa.gov/web/guest/jtwc' 
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Google_DRive_ID);
var exportUrl = RESOURCE_URL
var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl)
folder.createFile(FILE_NAME, data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the source of `https://metoc.ndbc.noaa.gov/web/guest/jtwc`, it was found that the source you want is included in `iframe` with the `id="_48_INSTANCE_0SiamlX2KcM6_iframe"`. The source URL is `src="/ProductFeeds-portlet/img/jtwc/html/coop.jsp?"`. When your script is modified using the URL, it is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
var root = "https://metoc.ndbc.noaa.gov";
var src = "/ProductFeeds-portlet/img/jtwc/html/coop.jsp?"; // You can also use "/ProductFeeds-portlet/img/jtwc/html/coop.jsp"

var FILE_NAME = 'data.txt'
var Google_DRive_ID = 'your google drive folder id'
var RESOURCE_URL = root + src;
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Google_DRive_ID);
var exportUrl = RESOURCE_URL
var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl)
folder.createFile(FILE_NAME, data)
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, First of all, thanks for your enlightenment. I learnt from you the use of 'root' + 'src'. Actually, the 'cool.jsp' doesn't get the information I need. But I just found another 'src' i.e. src = "/RSSFeeds-portlet/img/jtwc/jtwc.rss?" + (new Date()).getTime()". I used it. It finally works now. Thanks.

Comment: @warsur ``jtwc.rss`` is included in ``coop.jsp``. I couldn't notice that what you want is it. I'm sorry for taking your time. But I'm glad your problem was solved.